# Why can the noun phrase “l'esprit tranquille” be used like an adverb?

Tags: expressions, adverbes

> Partez **l'esprit tranquille** en vacances en nous laissant nous occuper de votre installation.

On several separate occasions, I have heard native French speakers around me use the phrase « l'esprit tranquille » like an adverb. It rubbed off on me, and now I use it in conversation myself.

The thing is, I would expect some additional word like « ***avec*** l'esprit tranquille » to make it grammatically correct. I wonder if « l'esprit tranquille » is an exceptional case where a noun phrase is used like an adverb? Or are there other similar expressions?

Comment: Also compare English "He fell head first."

Comment: @LukeSawczak Indeed. "France won hands down."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are many other expressions like this one, there are not always specific idioms, it's also a valid structure where a nominal group is used with an adverbial meaning. A few examples coming to mind :

> Partir **la fleur au fusil** *(specific idiom)*
>
> Travailler **les yeux baissés** *(I just composed this one, it's not a specific expression)*
>
> Mâcher **la bouche ouverte** *(unspecific, although probably used quite often)*

You can see that for each of these examples, the preposition "avec" that you expected is not only absent, it would be redundant and may sound odd to some.

Comment: Hi. Can you use other adjectives in the phrase « l'esprit + adjective »?

Comment: @Alone-zee Yes. L'esprit serein, l'esprit confus, l'esprit léger ...anything goes as long as it makes sense in the context.

Comment: Oh, I see. Can you come up with a sentence where "l'esprit confus" is used like an adverb without "avoir/avec"?

Comment: *« Avant même de recevoir cette missive, la jeune femme avançait dans la vie l’esprit confus. »* John Burnside, L'été des noyés, 2014.

Comment: Agreed - I see this structure often, and without "avec". It seems to work particularly well with elements of oneself (perhaps on the model of sentences like "J'ai -la partie du corps- -modifiant-"?).